# Can the Gephi node renderer preserve the original node opacity?

Tags: gephi

My graph is saved as a GEXF file with node colors specified as r,g,b,a. I see a change to the ImporterGEXF from 0.8 to 0.9.1 which preserves the opacity value, this is great!

But when I export the graph as a PDF or PNG the opacity for all nodes is taken from `PreviewProperty.NODE_OPACITY`. Is there any way to use the value that was originally associated with the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contributed a patch to Gephi to support this; it's available in the current release.